# C++ a circular chain of linked nodes with one external pointer

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I am asked to write a link-based implementation of a queue that uses a circular linked chain of nodes to represent the elements in a queue.

Also to only use a single tail pointer like so:
[Figure 14-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfv79.jpg)

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot connect the back node pointer to the first as I am only allowed to use a single tail pointer.

The class I am using:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Node.h"

template<class T>
class CircularLinkedQueue : public Queue<T> {
private:
    Node<T>* back;
    int length;
public:
    CircularLinkedQueue();
    virtual ~CircularLinkedQueue();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool enqueue(T* element);
    T* dequeue();
    T* peek() const;
};
```

The code line I am having trouble with:

```
back->setNext(??);     // How do I connect it to the front?
```

Please help point me in the right direction, I've been searching around for something similar but I cannot find anything.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are adding a node at the end of the list just point that to the first node itself for eg

```
T* enqueue(T* element){
if(Queue == NULL){
element.setNext(element);
return element;}
T* cur=queue;
while(cur->next != queue)cur=cur->next;
cur->next=element;
element->next=queue;
return queue;}
```

Basically what the code does is while entering a new element it changes the pointer of the just added element to point to the starting of the queue that is the root element Note that I'm inserting the element from the back

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. What I am dealing with is just one node and the reason it is placed in the back is that so I do not have to iterate through the linked list to get to the front. The back has to simply point(setNext()) to the front with no iterators and no additional external pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In a circular linked queue with a single external pointer to the rear of the queue, each node in the queue should have a data component and a next component.

The benefit of having a single external pointer to the rear of the queue is that you have instant access to both the rear of the queue and the front of the queue.

To access the front of the queue, use the external pointer to access the rear node's "next" component. Like this: nodePtr front = back->next;

Now you have an external pointer (nodePtr) to the front of the queue.